# Tensor Manipulation in Wald's General Relativity by Robert M. Wald at page 334

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

I don't understand the example, just after the "i.e.", at the end of the paragraph in the image. Why is it zero when the condition is fulfilled?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $- T^a{}_b\chi^b$ points in the direction of $\chi^a$, we may write $- T^a{}_b\chi^b = k\chi^a$ for some constant $k$, and hence the expression you mentioned becomes $\chi_{[c}T_{a]b}\chi^b = - k\chi_{[c}\chi_{a]} = 0$.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much@@